# Flashing between page loads

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, dom-events

On a website, I'm experiencing a "flash" of white that occurs between page loads. It looks bad because I'm using a background image and when the page loads, the background images flash before it comes onto the screen ([take a look for yourself](http://bigtim.ca)). This issues occurs in chrome and IE but not in firefox.

The site has a way of preloading stuff. Every element on the page is in a div wrapper `#website` which is initially at `display:none`, and every image is in a div wrapper `#website-images` which is also hidden. Then the site (using a jquery plugin) checks to see if all the images in `#website-images` are done loading, once they are a cookie is set to remember that this user has loaded the images already so it won't go through the preloading process once they go to another page or reload the current one, then a call to `$("#website").show()` is made to display the webpage.

So what could be causing this flickering between the page loads? Is it my way of preloading images? I've added different doctypes, and changed meta information but NOTHING has worked. I'm really lost here, does anyone have any ideas or insights?

Comment: What I really want to do is have the page render nothing until the IMG is fully loaded, then render the whole page. If I style body as display:none and put JavaScript at the end of the body to set style of body back to block there is still a white flash, in Firefox and Chrome. I think the actual loading of an img is done after the whole page has been rendered? Seems impossible to eliminate the white flash; strange.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is happening because the DOMLoaded event is fired enough milliseconds before the page actually renders.

In a nutshell, this means you have to optimise your website's speed. This doesn't mean to make it download *faster*, but it means to download in the correct order, in a *non-blocking* way.

## Step one: Your markup

1)
It seems there is a lot you can do to optimise your markup. Firstly, the order of stylesheets and JavaScripts can be optimised. To ensure CSS files are downloaded asynchronously, you always have to include external CSS before external JavaScript files. `style.css` is downloaded after some/all of your JavaScript calls.

There is 1 script block found in the head between an external CSS file and another resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS file, or after the next resource.

2)
Your main JavaScript file is inline within your markup. Not only does this block the page download until the script has finished downloading, but having it *before* your content is probably causing (or adding to) the white flash.

Loading your script asynchronously in the head is my preferred method. You will then have to trigger your script when the DOM has finished loading, or you can achieve the same result by placing the script at the bottom of the body tag.

## Step two: Harness the browser's capabilities

1) Looking at the http headers, there are 28 items being served as separate HTTP calls, that are not being cached on the browser (including the html pages, jpg images, stylesheets and JavaScript files).

These items are explicitly non-cacheable, and this can be easily fixed by editing your webserver's configuration.

2) Enable gzip compression. Most web browsers (yes, even IE) supports gzip decompression, and most (if not all) web servers support compressing using gzip. You could even go overkill and look into SPDY, which is an alternative lighter HTTP protocol (supported in Chrome and Firefox).

## Step three: Content serving

There are around 30 individual items being served from your domain. Firstly, consider how you could reduce this number of requests. 30 HTTP requests per page view is a lot. You can combat this using the following methods:

1) Paralleled downloads across multiple hostnames. Browsers currently limit the number of concurrent connections to a single domain. Serving your images from a separate domain (for example, img.bigtim.ca) can allow them to be served in parallel to other content.

2) Combine multiple items into one. Many items that are downloaded are purely style content, such as the logo, menu elements, etc. These can be combined into a single image (downloaded only once), and split using CSS. This is called CSS spriting. Stack Overflow does this: [look here](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=2).

3) If you cannot reduce the amount of items needing downloading, you could reduce the load on your server (and in turn, the client's browser) by serving static content from a cookieless domain. Stack Overflow does this with all their static content such as images, stylesheets and scripts.

## Step four: Optimise your own code

There's only so much that HTTP and browser technology can do to help your website's speed. This last step is down to you.

1) Is there any reason you choose to host jquery yourself? Jquery's download page shows multiple CDNs where you can point to for speedy, cached script downloading.

2) There are currently over 20 unused CSS rules within your stylesheets (that's 36% of your entire CSS file). Have a re-think of what is really needed.

3) The main chunk of JavaScript (at the top of your body tag) seems to be a hack to attempt to speed things up, but is probably not helping anything.

A cookie is being set to specify whether or not the page has faded in yet. Not only are you using JavaScript to perform a transition which can happily be performed by CSS, but more than half of the script is used to define the functionality for reading and writing the cookie.

Seeing things like this: `$("body").css ("background-image", "url('images/background.png')");` and `$("#website").show ();` usually gets me ranting about  "separation of concerns", but this answer is long enough now so hopefully you can see that it is bad practice to mix style and functionality in the same code.

> Addendum: Looking at the code, there is no need for jquery at all to
>   perform what you are doing. But then again, there is no need to
>   perform what you are doing, so you could probably do better without any
>   JavaScript at all.

Comment: Greg, How do you feel about Separation of Concerns with the "new" frontend JS frameworks?

Comment: @johnny in one word: terrible. We've gone for decades learning about the benefits of separating our HTML, JS and CSS and new Frameworks come along and persistently continue breaking the web with no recourse.

Comment: So would you stay with jQuery or go straight up JS or both?

Comment: @johnny it depends. I like to keep as much logic on the server as possible, so JavaScript usage these days is minimal for me, and jQuery would be overkill. However if you're doing heavy JavaScript, there's still room for the cross browser API it provides.

Answer (score 8):

Move your javascript to the end of the html just before closing the body tags. Sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread but here is a hack I tried and works.
The idea is not to display anything while CSS is loaded completely.

in html file:

```
<body style="display:none">
```

in your CSS, the last line:

```
body{display:block !important}
```

Comment: For me, this has no effect. The big white flash still occurs before a 4.5MB IMG element is rendered. I'm using STYLE tags, not external CSS, because I'm using Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is render-blocking. 
Divide you CSS into 2 parts -

- Critical CSS
- Non-Critical CSS

Make Critical CSS load with the page. It should come embedded within the head tag.
Make Non-critical CSS lazy load via ajax.

This will result in serious performance optimization in your webpage leading to less white-screen time.

Also, you can consider loading your Javascript in async/defer way.